# Paypal call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile with a different value of the original checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In my business logic I need to create a profile payment with an amount different from the one the user sees on the checkout page.

That's because in the paypal classic checkout he is buying something and after that subscribing to a different product.

There's any problem sending a different 'AMT' from the one provided previously to the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `INITAMT` in [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

**INITAMT**

(Optional) Initial non-recurring payment amount due immediately upon profile creation. Use an initial amount for enrolment or set-up fees.

Comment: But that's not what I want. The question is, since paypal gives me no choice but to call "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" AFTER the checkout itself, can I use any AMT I want? I found no restrains in the documentation, but it's a weird payment flow they have. I should be able to set the recurring value BEFORE I redirect the user to paypal, so he can see what he is agreeing to, not after, where everything is made transparently with API.